# Tools to trace WCF Rest with SSL Requests and responses

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

Please tell me the tools to trace the HTTP /HTTPS Requests / responses for WCF Restful serivices.

I have using Fiddler. Actually i am testing for HTTPS. So i wanna see whether my post requests and responses are going in encrypted or not.

please tell me the tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark. Fiddler is a good start in that it allows you to read the requests and responses, but it won't allow you to sniff the network connection itself in order to see what's traveling over the wire.

So get a copy of Wireshark (it's free and there's plenty of documentation on how to use it) and set it up to sniff a port/connection. Once that's done and you've got Wireshark configured, run the sniffer on an unencrypted request/response and then another on an encrypted transaction. You should see the difference pretty clearly, like in the pictures below. One you can read, the other you can't.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am not getting the output as you shown in the first picture. but it is HTTPS protocol with SSL certificate. Is there any way to look ?

Comment: You should see roughly what you see here. When you examine the sniff package from Wireshark, you should be able to read the plain text in the unencrypted transmission, and not be able to read the encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I think `WcfTestClient` will helps you to check the `request` and `response`. You find `WcfTestClient.exe` in this folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE**(In my case)

Comment: I know this tool. But it will not useful to trace the Requests and responses (if we want to see the encrypted data its not possible with this tool..??)